# Data warehouse with foreign key

Tags: database-design

I have data that I extract and from sam.gov and fpds.gov and a few other sources. and I throw the data in a warehouse. The sam data I just throw away at the end of the month and add in the updated data from sam.gov's public extracts.

I am not using a foreign key between the fpds and sam data but there is a relationship between them, and I am able to join them based on a certain key in the data. Should I create a FK relationship between the two tables or just continue without one?

There is a one-to-many relationship from sam -> fpds.

Comment: Why would you NOT want to put a foreign key in place?

Comment: Foreign keys are there to maintain data integrity and keep it consistent. Do you care more about performance than you do data integrity? Or vice versa? That would be your answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Shaulinator Whilst I can agree in principal, in reality it's very rare that anybody cares if a query takes 10ms longer than it once did - more context is needed for that assumption.

Comment: Many modern DBMS engines (you didn't mention yours) use constraint information for query optimization, so the difference in performance might be more substantial than "10 ms"

Comment: If one could only `CREATE` a constraint that the the optimizer could `RELY` on but cause the database to not validate ( `NOVALIDATE` ) the data upon creation and `DISABLE` the validation upon data load.........I wonder how that would improve performance.  But, that might be RDBMS specific.

Answer (score 1):

DWs normally go without FKs, since there's normally no DML apart from loading the data into its tables.  You want this to go as fast as possible, while the integrity should be guaranteed by your sources.

Comment: +1.  Generally I agree with this answer.  Since your two data sources in this situation are from two different sources, there's no guarantee of consistency between them.  Adding a foreign key on the DWH side would cause all sorts of problems.  The source should maintain consistency.  The DWH just displays whats there.